# Is it possible to trash a BIOS chip while updating it?

Tags: laptop, bios, dell-xps

I've an old Dell XPS Studio 1340 laptop, with BIOS version A11, that abruptly announced that it couldn't recognise its battery, and it stopped charging.. Reading that a BIOS update could help I got the latest one (A15) and applied it - dell supply it as a windows exe, but it refuses to run if there's no battery in the system. Given that this battery was useless, I used the `/forceit` command line param to the exe, to force the update to start

Around half way through the computer froze verifying some block. Rebooting it after a few hours, there's no life - after 30 seconds or so the volume buttons (mute, down, up) light up and the middle one flashes on and off

Some more reading around, and apparently a Phoenix bios can be recovered on this laptop thus:

- Obtain a copy of WINCRISIS - seems to be a tool that writes some boot loader/cut down version of dos/flashing tool to a USB
- Run the dell bios update tool with a command line arg of `/writeromfile` to extract a 2088kb ROM file. Incidentally, unpacking the exe with WinRAR produces a few files, including winphlash, but it doesn't produce a rom file
- Rename the 1340_a15.rom to BIOS.WPH and place it alongside wincris.exe
- Use WINCRIS.EXE (on windows XP - compatibility mode on a later OS is no good; I dug out an old XP laptop for this) to write a (small) USB flash drive. I used a 1GB drive that unusually has a flashing light - handy to tell if data is being read/written
- Pull the battery and the power supply out of the dell laptop. Connect the USB to any port, hold down the END key, connect the power, release the END key
- The laptop powers on and begins the bios recovery - nothing is shown on screen. The only indication that things are proceeding is the flashing light on the USB

The USB light flashes for a couple of minutes - so far all is proceeding as per the various guides I've read.. The light stops blinking and that's it - it'll sit like that for hours

I've tried the same technique with all the bios versions I can find on the dell website - A11, A14 and A15. Before all this it did have A11 on it, and I was hoping at least if the chip was bad and only half-flashed with A15, that reflashing with A11, even if it only half succeeded/froze at the same point, that it might realise a working machine - seems not

Couple of questions:

1. Is the ROM file (that I rename to bios.wph as per wincris' instructions) produced by the dell bios exe in the correct format for flashing according to this procedure?
2. Is it possible that the BIOS chip is faulty in some way and won't accept this flash/did the original flashing attempt ruin it somehow?
3. The original flashing attempt (in windows) asserted that it was backing up the existing bios - any ideas where this would be/would flashing it via this procedure stand any chance of success?

Answer (score 1):

Answering number 2, yes, it is possible for a flash update (or any software update that fails prematurely for that matter) to impact the system and make it unusable.  Normally the systems have a fail safe that will allow you to reflash but I have on a few occasions bricked a system or device only to simply discard it.

For the Dell you mentioned I found an [entry](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dell-Studio-XPS-1645-BIOS-problem/td-p/3538796) on the Dell website that might prove useful.  It sounds like you tried the recovery mode as indicated but there were several other hints and tips in the thread.

> To get the laptop to power on into BIOS recovery mode (with the side
>   LEDs turned orange), I had to hold down the end key, and then release
>   it at the same time as pressing the power button. I did this with only
>   AC power.

Comment: Unusable in the sense of failing to start the normal firmware, yes, but I believe the question was about whether the flash/eeprom could _physically_ be unable to accept any more writes?

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering the question I asked here, but an update of sorts: my BIOS chip may not be trashed after all.

I obtained another USB stick (a newer 32gb sandisk one this time) that was formatted as the full 32gb FAT32.

I replaced the phlash16.exe (v1.6.9.5) that came with wincrisis 1.0.0.4 (from https://www.bios-mods.com/bios-recovery/phoenix-bios-recovery/) with phlash16.exe v1.7.0.21 (from https://www.wimsbios.com/phoenixflasher.jsp)

I also placed bios v A11 next to wincris, rather than A15

I made another recovery disk with wincris.exe - wincris repartitioned/formatted the 32gb usb to be just 32mb FAT16 and copied all the relevant files. Again this was done from a bona fide 32bit windows XP machine rather than any newer machine/os in XP compatibility mode

I also reconnected the battery, though I doubt this made a difference, as it's completely toast

This time it worked out - followed the same procedure to initiate the flash though I didn't have any indication of progress/activity - the laptop rebooted after about 5 min and is back to as it was before it stopped working